# Best strategy when filling HTML page via javascript and ajax

Tags: javascript, performance

I have this HTML page that is filled via javascript with multiple ajax calls. I have this dictionary that is filled with some JSON text grabbed via ajax calls like in this example: (The actual code is over 1k lines)

```js
var dict = {}
$.ajax({async: false, type: 'GET', url: '/page/1', success: function(data)
{
    dict = JSON.parse(data);
    // {'name': 'foo', 'image': '42', 'user': 'bar_user'}

    $.ajax({async: false, type: 'GET', url: '/image/'+dict.image,
        success: function(data)
        {
            dict.image = JSON.parse(data);
            // {'low_res': 'l.jpg', 'high_res': 'h.jpg'}
        }

    $.ajax({async: false, type: 'GET', url: '/user/'+dict.user,
        success: function(data)
        {
            dict.user = JSON.parse(data);
            // {'email': 'bar@bar.com', 'image': '69'}

            $.ajax({async: false, type: 'GET', url: '/image/'+dict.user.image,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    dict.user.image = JSON.parse(data);
                    // {'low_res': 'l_2.jpg', 'high_res': 'h_2.jpg'}
                }
        }
}
```

This dictionary is used to fill the page using some functions like so:

```js
function fillImageDiv(img)
{
    $('div#image_container > img').attr('src',img.high_res)
}

function fillUserDiv(user)
{
    $('div#user_container > span').html(user.email);
    $('div#user_container > img').attr('src', user.image.low_res);
}

fillImageDiv(dict.image);
fillUserDiv(dict.user);
```

Having this in mind, what would be the best way to fill the page?

Would it be better to fill the whole dictionary and then fill the divs, or to fill each div as soon as the JSON was loaded into the dictionary?

Making the ajax calls asynchronous would make the dict fill faster, even when there is no multi-threading in javascript?

What about calling `fillImageDiv` and `fillUserDiv` asynchronously?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of performance, it would be best if you could just make one AJAX call to fill up your dictionary, and then fill in your `<div>` elements all in one go.  Those synchronous AJAX calls are going to hurt the responsiveness of your site more than anything else.

If you can't combine the AJAX calls, and your site won't have its interface affected by not having each of the separate components (image and user) together, then it would definitely be better to have them separately updated asynchronously.

If you do need to have both of them together, then you can use an asynchronous control flow library such as [caolan's async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) to more elegantly manage your parallel AJAX calls, and then update the DOM element in one go once the results are available.

In general, when you're talking about web and JavaScript performance, do the following things in order:

1. Minimize HTTP requests
2. Make your AJAX results cacheable
3. Minimize access to the DOM

The HTTP requests will generally be the bottleneck, and DOM manipulation right after that.